# How to fix a multiple form with the same name?

Tags: php, html, database, foreach

I'm setting up a new form service for people, and the form should get up to 4 inputs with the same name. The form has 2 double inputs, one for Money and another for Service Name.

#### HTML

```
<input name='budget[]' id='' placeholder='Product or Service' type='text' class='form-control'>
<input name='budget_price[]' id='currency' placeholder='Value' type='number' class='form-control'>

<input name='budget[]' id='' placeholder='Product or Service' type='text' class='form-control'>
<input name='budget_price[]' id='currency' placeholder='Value' type='number' class='form-control'>
```

How can I do a foreach to insert it in the db afterwards?

Comment: you would loop one of the arrays, and use the keys from that to access the others

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you'd need to loop one array and use key to access entry from the other.

Give this a go:

```
<?php
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$budgetPrice = $_POST['budget_price'];

foreach ($budget as $key => $entry) {
    $serviceName = $entry;
    $currency = $budgetPrice[$key];

    // insert $serviceName and $currency into DB
    // first iteration of loop is the first two inputs
}
```

Or if you want another way around (or can't choose which array to loop on), you could use `for` loop:

```
<?php
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$budgetPrice = $_POST['budget_price'];

$totalBudget = count($budget);

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalBudget; $i++) {
    $serviceName = $budget[$i];
    $currency = $budgetPrice[$i];

    // insert $serviceName and $currency into DB
    // first iteration of loop is the first two inputs
}
```

I assumed the logic for having no gap between numbers of elements in each of the array (eg. `count($budget) == count($budgetPrice)` returns `true`) is handled somewhere beforehand.

As per your last comment, you'd need to test if the variable is empty before inserting, as such:

```
<?php
if (!empty($serviceName)) {
    // insert $serviceName
}

if (!empty($currency)) {
    // insert $currency
}
```

Comment: yes its working but.. the code add the empty fields.. how can i only insert field with text?